# Dell Poweredge R710 Vmware Stand-by Mode slow to boot back up

Tags: vmware-esxi, dell-poweredge

I currently have Vmware ESXI 5 cluster with Dell Poweredge R710 hosts. I was told that its possible when a host goes into stand-by to have a "quick-boot" when it comes out. At this time I am waiting 7+ minutes. I have seen another cluster that boots out of stand-by in 30 seconds.

Is this a setting or part of IPMI or bios? If so how do i set this up?

Best way I can explain it Is i want the VM Host to Go to Sleep vs power off completely when in stand-by mode.

Comment: I think i might have found something http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/hpm-perf-vsphere5.pdf

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the [VMWare Distributed Power Management (DPM)](http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/Distributed-Power-Management-vSphere.pdf) functionality.

In your host config in the vSphere client, navigate to `Configuration -> Software -> Power Management`.

You can add your ILO/DRAC/IPMI settings in the resulting dialog.

[image]

Further configuration on policy definition is available in your cluster properties dialog... It's related to the DRS feature.

What version of VMWare licensing are you running?

Comment: ESXI 5.1.0, i already have the IMPI/iLO settings in place.

Comment: I'm asking about your license... This is only available in *Enterprise* or greater licensing.

Comment: I am running Vsphere enterprise. I can use stand-by mode etc but its just slow.

Comment: Check your server's BIOS settings and ensure that C-states and specifically, [P-states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface#Power_states) are enabled. (see: S3)

Comment: I have no option for p-state control that i can find in the bios. C-State is enabled and the power management is under os control.

Comment: I assume p-state is a Feature that is always on controlled by VMWARE HPM?